# ImageMagick Batch Montage

Tags: imagemagick

In my first trial with Cygwin, I managed a simple montage of 2 image files into a final one.

However, I would like to batch montage all .jpg files in a directory so to combine them Two by Two, and thus have like half the original number of images.

Could you help?

Comment: Yuck! You'll have to enable all that awful delayed expansion rubbish in Windows to list files pairwise. When you can list files pairwise, let me know and I'll tell you how to montage them - good luck!

Comment: Dear Mark, no, I do not want all possible combinations, I just want Pic1 to be next to Pic2 (Result1.jpg), then Pic3 next to Pic4 (Result2.jpg)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally try to avoid Windows, but you can do it something like this:

**GO.BAT**

```
DIR /B *.JPG | CSCRIPT /NOLOGO PAIRIMAGES.VBS
```

**PAIRIMAGES.VBS**

```
cnt=1
Do
   ' Read in first image name
   Im1  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   If WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream Then
      Wscript.Echo "WARNING: Unpaired file left over."
      Exit Do
   End If

   ' Read in second image name
   Im2  = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()

   ' Work out ImageMagick command, something like:
   '    convert im1.jpg im2.jpg +append result1.png
   cmd="convert " & Im1 & " " & Im2 & " +append " & result & cnt & ".png" 

   ' Show user the command, for debug purposes
   WScript.echo cmd

   ' Now execute it
   Set objShell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
   Set oExec = objShell.Exec(cmd)
   If WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream Then
      Wscript.Echo "Done"
      Exit Do
   End If
   cnt = cnt + 1
Loop
```

**Sample Output**

```
E:\>DIR /B *.JPG   | CSCRIPT /NOLOGO PAIRIMAGES.VBS
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg +append 1.png
convert 3.jpg 4.jpg +append 2.png
Done
```

If you want to align the tops of images with dissimilar sizes, use:

```
convert -gravity North ...
```

and change `North` to `East` if you want the centres aligned and to `-South` if you want the bottoms aligned.

Comment: By the way, if you have spaces and other nonsense in your filenames, you will need to add some quoting and treat my answer more as a proof of concept than production-ready code.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Windows indeed is giving me problems with the convert, but the loop works correctly, and this is enough for me now. I am downloading Debian Linux, and will soon have it installed for future ImageMagick works (I have tons of pictures! and I am making a Pseudo Reading Layout out of many book scans)